# Cordova/Gradle on linux platform

Tags: cordova, gradle, build

I have been building cordova projects with gradle just fine. But there is an error i get when building more than two projects. If I go back to the other projects I can build just fine, So I assume this is some memory limit but not sure.

```
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/home/fabianglace/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
studio
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
/usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: *Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace* -> try that

Comment: This provides a list of at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34). Nothing I can really take from the output.